# Tiny MCE paste big images issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I'm using the paste plugin on tiny-mce and the submit buttom send me the data of the images correctly on base64. The story so far is perfect. The problem becames when I trying to send a "big" image (it doesn't work with 700KB or upper images size), that the POST I recive on PHP is almost empty, it's like that:

content

```
<p><img alt="" /></p>
```

When I usually have

```
<p><img alt="" src="(all the base64 code)"/></p>
```

I think the problem is not about the size of the POST (I even sent 18 images together with no problem) but it should be a tinymce configuration issue.
Why is that?? Does it happen to someone else?

Comment: +1 good question (sry, i got no solution)